# Lens/OpenLens Error --> failed to get /version for clusterId:<ID>

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm creating this entry to share my findings after investigating a very frustrating issue with Lens/OpenLens, in which for a specific cluster we received the following type of errors:

`failed to get /version for clusterId:<ID> [Forbidden/Bad Gateway/Internal]`

(We are managing this cluster's RBAC using InfraHQ).

It occurred despite the fact that `kubectl` was working okay.
When assigning a `cluster-admin` role (infraHQ) --> allow all operations on everything, **it resolved the issue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, what resolved my issue, was the below addition to the relevant `ClusterRole` config under the `rules` field:

```
- nonResourceURLs:
  - /*
  verbs:
  - get
```

That way, Lens could run the `get` request on that non-resource URL, and hence, the cluster could load/open in Lens.

Comment: Which was the relevant ClusterRole in your case?

Comment: which ClusterRole is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just faced with this issue today and it looks like the cluster AuthZ has exhausted in the kubeconfig file. Kind of got old and not valid is what I presume.

Solution that worked for me is to access the cluster via normal way, be it on-prem or cloud provider. Once your cluster access with a defined clusterrole is saved to kubeconfig. Get that config file's content and present it to Lens does the job.

The reason why I believe that it has nothing to do with whether we are using cluster-admin role or only view based role is due to the fact that in Lens we provide the kubeconfig file which was pre-authorized kubeconfig authorization and certs aligned to the access. They could have expired and thus the loss of access

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything on the internet but had no luck. However, opening the Lens via the launcher seems to have caused this issue, and I tried to run it from the terminal using `open /Applications/Lens.app/` and it solved my problem.

Using a Mac with Iterm2.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbled upon this issue, I have resolved my issue by
Executing the command:

`aws eks --region ${your_eks_region} update-kubeconfig --name ${eks_cluster_name} --profile ${aws_profile}`

In my case, I missed the `--profile` parameter that's why I'm getting the said issue.